# How to prevent VS Code auto importing from 'react-native-web'?

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code

When I type `View`, I expect VS Code to automatically `import { View } from 'react-native';` but what is does is `import { View } from 'react-native-web';`. The problem is that anything imported from 'react-native-web' creates errors and never seems to work.
[image]

What are the procedures to prevent this from happening? I am tired of manually importing every elements from 'react-native'.

PS. I am using *Auto Import* VS Code extension.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am actually facing a similar 'bug'. However, what you can do is you can install `@types/react-native` package.

For npm: `npm install --save-dev @types/react-native`

For yarn: `yarn add --dev @types/react-native`

This is just a workaround, because it used to work without that Typescript package before. Alas, this will at least save you from manually importing the elements.

Also, I'm assuming that you already have `react-native-tools` extension installed.

Comment: Yes, I have `react-native-tools` installed. Is that unnecessary? I am new to react native.

Comment: `react-native-tools` is necessary. 
I think what's happening is a conflict between `react-native` and `react-native-web`, so VS Code is showing only `react-native-web` components.

Did you try installing the `@types/react-native` dependency?

Comment: I was having the same issue, easy fix but annoying when you forgot. Running `npm install --save @types/react-native` at least now gives me both options. Thanks!

Comment: @OrdinaryProbably If it worked for you, can you please mark it as the accepted answer?

Comment: Isn't it better to use "npm install --save-dev @types/react-native" instead of using "--save" as it's only useful during development?